# Conditional Radon Nikodym

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

I am having some trouble conceptualizing and calculating a *conditional* RN derivative. When using this definition:

[image: RN Theorem]

I can see that if $\mathbb{Q} \ll \mathbb{P}$:
$$\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}(g) = \int g(\omega) \mathbb{Q}(\mathsf d\omega) = \int g(\omega) f(\omega) \mathbb{P}(\mathsf d\omega) = \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P}(gf)$$

where $f$ is the RN derivative defined by: 
$$f = \frac{\mathsf d\mathbb{Q}}{\mathsf d\mathbb{P}}$$

Im having trouble with the following relation:
$$\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}(g\mid\mathcal{Y}) \stackrel{?}{=} \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P}(g \tilde{f}\mid \mathcal{Y})$$

where $\tilde{f}$ is something like a *conditional* RN derivative:
$$\tilde{f} \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{d\mathbb{Q}_{(\cdot \mid \mathcal{Y})}}{d\mathbb{P}_{(\cdot \mid \mathcal{Y})}} \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}}{?}$$

I tried searching for "conditional RN derivative" and the like but couldn't find an appropriate source. If someone could help me conceptually understand as well as mechanically calculate this I'd very much appreciate it!

EDIT: 
To clarify, If I start from $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ and form the conditional measures (from Bayes rule) $\mathbb{P}(\cdot | \mathcal{Y})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\cdot | \mathcal{Y})$ after gathering some evidence/observations, I know I can write:

$$\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}(\cdot|\mathcal{Y})}(g|\mathcal{Y}) = \int g(\omega) \mathbb{Q}( \cdot | \mathcal{Y})$$

What is the $\tilde{f}$ that makes the following true?

$$\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}(\cdot|\mathcal{Y})}(g|\mathcal{Y}) = \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}(\cdot | \mathcal{Y})}(g \tilde{f} | \mathcal{Y})$$

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}(\cdot \mid {\mathcal{Y}})$ is not a measure. It is a random variable. So one cannot treat it  as  a measure. Maybe I missed your point?

Comment: To compute$\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}(g \mid \mathcal{Y})$, you do not need $\mathbb{Q}(\cdot \mid \mathcal{Y})$. Here, $\mathbb{Q}(\cdot \mid \mathcal{Y})$ is usually called the regular conditional probability, which does not necessarily exist.

Comment: Which is why we can use the RN derivative described in your answer to compute it under $\mathbb{P}(\cdot|\mathcal{Y})$ correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, 
\begin{align*}
\tilde{f} = \frac{f}{\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}(f \mid \mathcal{Y})}.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}(g \mid \mathcal{Y}) = \frac{\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}(f g\mid \mathcal{Y})}{\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}(f \mid \mathcal{Y})}.
\end{align*}
This is the "abstract Bayes formula".

Comment: Thank you very much! I found this under some measure theoretic lecture notes. If you dont' mind, can you provide some intuition as to how that form relates to the "traditional Bayes" ideas of a "prior", "likelihood" and "posterior"? Thanks!

Comment: This result is proved in Robert J. Elliott, Lakhdar Aggoun, John B. Moore:          
Hidden Markov Models Estimation and Control as Theorem 3.2 (Conditional             
Bayes Theorem) on p23:                                                              
http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~john/papers/BOOK/B05.PDF